# Entering password as su root in centos doesn't let me type the password. How to type the password, I am trying to install a sdk on my computer

Tags: centos-7

I am trying to install a sdk on my centos 7 machine but when I open a ternminal to un tar the file, it doesn't work. When I type su root, it asks for a password. When I try to enter the password, it won't let me type anything. I can see a black blinking square which doesn't accept any characters

Comment: Are you entering your password or root's? Have you tried using sudo?

Answer (score 1):

Linux commands, when requesting a password, won't echo the characters you type as a security measure.

The system is still accepting your input.  Type your password even if it doesn't echo back on the screen, and then press Enter, and if the password is correct, you will be able to proceed.

Also, `su` by default will switch user to `root`, so you can just type `su` and not `su root`.